# How to compile list of .as files into a single .swf?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flexbuilder

Hello i'm using flex to compile .as files.I have more number of .as files, i just want to compile all the files as a single .swf. Can any please tell me how to do that?

thanks,

Answer (score 5):

The common approach to do this (force some classes to be included into compiled swf) is just list these classes into main compiled class, like:

```
package
{
import my.package.Class1;
import my.package.Class2;

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    Class1;
    Class2;

    public function Main()
    {
    }
}
}
```